# Use Model object value in Client template Telerik Grid mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I need to display two different values in the grid based on the Model Object property.I am able to do it using Template but not client template.
How to do it?

I have used the below code but i am getting error that IsContractORPO is undefined.

```
@{
    Model.IsContractORPO = "P"; 
}
<div>
    @{Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.TestList)
                      .Name("testGrid")
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(col => col.FTE);

                  columns
                      .Template(@<text>@if (Model.IsContractORPO == "C")
                                       {<div>@item.FTE</div>}
                                       else if (Model.IsContractORPO == "P")
                                       {<div>-</div>}</text>).Title("FTETestColumn")
                      .ClientTemplate("<# if (model.IsContractORPO == 'C') { #> <div><#=FTE#></div><# } else if(model.IsContractORPO == 'P'){ #><div>-</div><# } #>");

                  columns.Bound(col => col.BalanceAmount);
                  columns.Bound(col => col.BalanceUnits);
              })
              .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("onDataBinding"))
              .Render();
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After sometime of analysis, i came to know that we can use a model property in the client template by making it as a script variable.
The following code solved the Issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isContractORPO = '@Model.IsContractORPO';
</script>
```

And the client template would be like

```
ClientTemplate("<# if (isContractORPO == 'C') { #> <div><#=FTE#></div><# } else if(isContractORPO == 'P'){ #><div>-</div><# } #>");
```